# How to convert all CSV files in a folder to data frames and append them in a single data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple CSV files in C:\data\ folder. I want to know how to convert all of them into data frames and append them to one single data frame. They all have the same column names.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: I'm trying to use append function to append dataframes from the bottom, not trying to lookup values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will combine all the CSV files in 'C:\Data\Folder' into one dataframe.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r'C:\Data\Folder')

files = glob.glob('*.csv')

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files ]).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
combined_csv = pd.concat( [ pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames ] )
```

If you want everything in one file, this should work;

```
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False )
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason it doesn't work, I'll have to try again.

Comment: @kalapangha Could you describe the error in detail?